# Finding a line integral of $F(x,y) = (3x^2\cos y + 2\cos x, -x^3\sin y)$ along a given curve.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form, vector-fields

Let $F$ : $R^2 \to R^2$ be the vector field F(x,y) = ($3x^2cosy+2cosx,-x^3siny$) and $\gamma$ : [$0$,$\pi$]$\to$$R^2$ be the curve $\gamma(t)=(t,(\pi-t)^2)$. Find the line integral of $F$ along $γ$ ?

I tried to solve the problem:
Firstly I found F($\gamma(t)$) = ($3t^2cos(\pi-t)^2+2cost$,$-t^3sin(\pi-t)^2$).
Secondly I found the derivative of $\gamma'(t)$ = (1,-2($\pi$-t))
The next thing which I have to do is finding the dot product of F($\gamma(t)$) and $\gamma'(t)$. I found it but I could not take integral from it.

Comment: Since you're a new user I'll mention this instead of downvoting -- in order to get the best shot at getting help with this question, you should show us what work you've already done or tried, even (especially) if it's wrong. Since this is a community filled with mathematicians, it's generally frowned upon to simply give someone an answer when they haven't tried it themselves, because that inhibits learning.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. We first need the vector field evaluated along the given curve:
$$
\vec{F}(\vec{\gamma}(t))=(3t^2\cos((\pi-t)^2)  + 2\cos t, -t^3\sin((\pi-t)^2))
$$ next we need the derivative of the parameterization
$$
\vec{\gamma'(t)}=(1,-2(\pi-t)).
$$ Finally, let’s get the dot product
$$
\begin{align}
\vec{F}(\vec{\gamma}(t))\cdot \vec{\gamma'(t)}&=(3t^2\cos((\pi-t)^2)+2\cos t)\cdot 1+(-t^3\sin((\pi-t)^2))\cdot (-2(\pi-t))
\\\\&=3t^2\cos((\pi-t)^2)+2\cos t+2t^3(\pi-t)\sin((\pi-t)^2))
\end{align}
$$ then we have to evaluate
$$
\int_{C}\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{\gamma}=\int_0^{\pi}\vec{F}(\vec{\gamma}(t))\cdot \vec{\gamma'(t)}\:dt.
$$
Can you take it from here?

---

> Edit. One may integrate, just observing that
>   $$
> (t^3\cos((\pi-t)^2))'=3t^2\cos((\pi-t)^2)+2t^3(\pi-t)\sin((\pi-t)^2).
> $$

Answer (score 1):

Look the path is from $\;(0,\pi^2)\;$ to $\;(\pi,0)\;$ , and the vector field is conservative because

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(3x^2\cos y+2\cos x)=-3x^2\sin y=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(-x^3\sin y)$$

Then we can go between those two points as we want and not necessarily on $\;\gamma\;$, so I choose the straight lines from $\;(0,\pi^2)\;$ to origin, and then from origin to $\;(0,\pi)\;$ :

$$r_1(t):=t(0,0)+(1-t)(0,\pi^2)=\left(0\,,\,\,\pi^2(1-t)\right)\,,\;\;0\le t\le 1$$
 and then

$$r_2(t):=t(\pi,0)+(1-t)(0,0)=(\pi t,0)\,,\,\,0\le t\le 1$$
and the line integrals are

$$\int_0^1 F(r_1(t))r_1'(t)dt=\int_0^1\left(0,0\right)\left(0,\,-\pi^2\right)dt=\int_0^10\,dt=0$$

$$\int_0^1F(r_2(t))r_2'(t)dt=\int_0^1\left(3\pi^2t^2+2\cos\pi t,\,0\right)\left(\pi,0\right)dt=$$

$$=3\pi^3\int_0^1 t^2dt+2\pi\int_0^1\cos\pi t\,dt=\pi^3$$

Answer (score 1):

A different approach is to notice that $F$ is conservative. You can thus instead compute the integral either by choosing a more convenient path, as in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1848440/265466), or you can find a scalar potential $\phi$ such that $F=\nabla\phi$ and evaluate $\phi(g(\pi))-\phi(g(0))$.

There are a couple of ways to find $\phi$. One method is to alternately integrate and differentiate the components of $F$ with respect to its parameters: $$\phi(x,y) = \int 3x^2\cos y+2\cos x\,dx = 2\sin x+x^3\cos y+h(y)$$ and ${\partial\phi\over\partial y}=-x^3\sin y+h'(y) = -x^3\sin y$, the $y$-component of $F$, which means that $h=\text{const}$. Since we’ll be subtracting two values of $\phi$ from each other, we can take $h$ to be zero for simplicity.

Alternatively, since $F$ is defined in a star-shaped region relative to the origin, we can directly compute $$\phi(x,y)=\int_0^1F(tx,ty)\cdot(x,y)\,dt,$$ which is just the line integral of $F$ along the segment joining the origin to the point $(x,y)$. For this problem, the first method looks simpler.